# using nested fragments or changing tablayout adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

i have this interface in my app

[image]

by choosing each item in bottomNavigation , the tab layout will change

[image]

my question is should i make a fragment for each of the bottom navigation items and then put the tab layouts inside that fragments ?

or make only one tab layout in activity and change the adapter of the tab layout in respond to selection of the bottom navigation items ?

Comment: layout is pretty straightforward. The bottom sheet has different fragments and each fragment has tab layout. I would prefer option 1 (modularity over generic)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the problem is each tab will load a fragment as well . don't you think this makes it more complicated ??

Comment: then use child fragment manager. I don't see any problem. However nesting fragment is not advisable. But your view demands

Comment: thank you very much